# How to adjust and position divs inside other div

Tags: html, css, web

I'm learning HTML and I'm trying to make a header in which there will be useful links. I've made this with a large div and 4 divs inside it but small divs aren't located inside that div, see it here: [My webpage](http://ivykoko1.esy.es/pagina.html)

My css code is:

```
#header{
        width:1200px;
        height:25px;
        background-color:#0A475C;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-600px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
#login{
        width:300px;
        position:relative;
        line-height:25px;
        left:0px;
        text-align:center;
}
#allroms{
        width:400px;
        line-height:25px
        position:relative;
        left:300px;
        text-align:center;
}
#sobremi{
        width:300px;
        line-height:25px;
        position:relative;
        left:600px;
        text-align:center;
}
#downloads{
        width:300px;
        position:relative;
        line-height:25px;
        left:900px;
        text-align:center;
}
```

And html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pagina.css">
        <title>Mi página</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="login"><a href="pagina/login.html">Log-in</a></div>
            <div id="allroms"><a href="pagina/roms.html">Todas las ROMS</a></div>
            <div id="sobremi"><a href="pagina/sobremi.html">Sobre mí</a></div>
            <div id="downloads"><a href="pagina/downloads.html">Descargas</a></div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Just solved it, had to change position:relative; to position:absolute;

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand positioning first.

Your `child div's` should be `absolute` and parent `div relative`.

Please refer the given link for examples.
[Positioning examples:](http://www.webdevdoor.com/html-css/css-position-child-div-parent/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not best practice to use absolute positioning in sth as simply as menu. In this case toy can simply use `float: left` on your 'small' divs, and position it with adding some `class` which contains `float: left` and margins or sth.

It will be very useful if you want to add some new item to your menu in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The parent (#header) shouldn't be absolute, make it relative. And the divs inside can be absolute. But this kind of positioning is not recommendable for menus.

Rather use `float` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/VKewr/